# Adding Razor content inside Jquery Ajax call

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, razor

I am trying to add asp.net mvc razor code inside jquery ajax success function. Any idea on tweaking this to work?

```
$.ajax({
  url: controllerUrl,
  type: 'POST',
  data: { id: 1 },
  success: function (response) {
    //adding asp.net mvc razor code
    @Html.Partial("GetDetails", Model)   
  }
));
)};
```

Comment: This would load a partial view into your ajax success callback... what's the issue?

Comment: Ah, is this in a separate javascript file? You'd have to run it through the MVC runtime if that's the case. Is there no way to render your partial view from your `View` and pass the results to a javascript function that passes it to this ajax call?

Comment: This seems to be good suggestion. I am trying that way. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Cool, I have to do it a fair amount, especially when I need to pass my application path to a javascript object so my paths don't break between my dev and prod environments. e.g. `obj.init('@Url.Content("~")')`;